# Can't edit Local Security Policy

Tags: windows, security, remote-desktop, administrator, group-policy

I'm trying to add users to the **Access this computer from the network** User Rights Assignment policy but the 'Add' button is disabled:

[image]

I'm connecting to the machine via RDP using the local Administrator account (not a domain user). I've also tried to do the same with a domain user that is in the Administrators group but the result is the same.

How can I add a user to this policy?

The machine is running Windows 7.

Comment: *You need to be using a domain user in the Administrator user group*

Comment: I am using it (the built-in account..), but I login via RDP. does it matter?

Comment: Your not using one, you indicated your using the local Administrator account, you need to be using a user connected to the domain with Administrator permissions.

Comment: I also tried that . it's the same

Comment: Update your question;  If I had know that;  I could have saved time responding.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot edit this User Rights Assignment policy because this setting is being managed by a domain-based Group Policy.  In this case, the domain Group Policy setting has precedence and you are prevented from modifying the policy via Local Group Policy.

To modify this policy, either:

1. Modify the policy in the applicable domain Group Policy Object.
2. Prevent any domain-based GPOs from specifying this setting, then edit the computer's Local Group Policy.

Comment: where can I find this policy in the GPO?

Comment: `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment`